# Does limiting a query improves perfomance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Would limiting a query to one (or more) result(s) have any noticeable impact on the performance?

For example:

`q := datastore.NewQuery("User").Filter("Name =", uniqueUsername)`

vs.

`q := datastore.NewQuery("User").Filter("Name =", uniqueUsername).Limit(1)`

Comment: If you have a unique username, you may want to make that the entity's key. Looking up an entity by key is *much* faster than querying.

Comment: @JasonHall I'm already doing this, this was just the first short example which I could imagine :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if there is only one entity that matches the query, I wouldn't expect to see any difference in those two queries. (But feel free to try it out for yourself to find out!)